# I want to add a widget to my site as follows:

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to add a widget to my site as follows:

```
<script src="https://widgets.coingecko.com/coingecko-coin-price-marquee-widget.js"></script>
      <coingecko-coin-price-marquee-widget coin-ids="bitcoin,ethereum,eos,ripple,litecoin" Currency = USD
                                           background-color="#ffffff" locale="en"></coinecko-coin-price-marquee-widget>
```

My site is written using LiveWire and is a full component
Now the problem is that I want to put the widget in one of these components and display it, but I can't!

But it runs without problems in the plan
where is the problem from